# Trouble inflating my SwipeRefreshLayout. Nothing's blocking the UI, not showing any errors and everything's been migrated to androidx. Any ideas?

Tags: java, android, androidx, loader, swiperefreshlayout

```
package crysalis.example.xyzreader.ui;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import com.example.xyzreader.R;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import crysalis.example.xyzreader.data.ArticleLoader;
import crysalis.example.xyzreader.data.ItemsContract;
import crysalis.example.xyzreader.data.UpdaterService;

/**
 * An activity representing a list of Articles. This activity has different presentations for
 * handset and tablet-size devices. On handsets, the activity presents a list of items, which when
 * touched, lead to a {@link ArticleDetailActivity} representing item details. On tablets, the
 * activity presents a grid of items as cards.
 */
public class ArticleListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String TAG = ArticleListActivity.class.toString();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss");
    // Use default locale format
    private SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    // Most time functions can only handle 1902 - 2037
    private GregorianCalendar START_OF_EPOCH = new GregorianCalendar(2,1,1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_list);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        final View toolbarContainerView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_container);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            refresh();
        }
    }

    private void refresh() {
        startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(mRefreshingReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(UpdaterService.BROADCAST_ACTION_STATE_CHANGE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mRefreshingReceiver);
    }

    private boolean mIsRefreshing = false;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRefreshingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (UpdaterService.BROADCAST_ACTION_STATE_CHANGE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                mIsRefreshing = intent.getBooleanExtra(UpdaterService.EXTRA_REFRESHING, false);
                updateRefreshingUI();
            }
        }
    };

    private void updateRefreshingUI() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(mIsRefreshing);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
//        return new ArticleLoader(getApplicationContext());
        return ArticleLoader.newAllArticlesInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull androidx.loader.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(data);
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.list_column_count);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm =
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(sglm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull androidx.loader.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    }

    private class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        private Cursor mCursor;

        public Adapter(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            return mCursor.getLong(ArticleLoader.Query._ID);
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            ItemsContract.Items.buildItemUri(getItemId(vh.getAdapterPosition()))));
                }
            });
            return vh;
        }

        private Date parsePublishedDate() {
            try {
                String date = mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.PUBLISHED_DATE);
                return dateFormat.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "passing today's date");
                return new Date();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            holder.titleView.setText(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.TITLE));
            Date publishedDate = parsePublishedDate();
            if (!publishedDate.before(START_OF_EPOCH.getTime())) {

                holder.subtitleView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                        DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                                publishedDate.getTime(),
                                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS,
                                DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString()
                                + "<br/>" + " by "
                                + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AUTHOR)));
            } else {
                holder.subtitleView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                        outputFormat.format(publishedDate)
                        + "<br/>" + " by "
                        + mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.AUTHOR)));
            }
            holder.thumbnailView.setImageUrl(
                    mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.THUMB_URL),
                    ImageLoaderHelper.getInstance(ArticleListActivity.this).getImageLoader());
            holder.thumbnailView.setAspectRatio(mCursor.getFloat(ArticleLoader.Query.ASPECT_RATIO));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public DynamicHeightNetworkImageView thumbnailView;
        public TextView titleView;
        public TextView subtitleView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnailView = (DynamicHeightNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
            subtitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_subtitle);
        }
    }
}
```

The logcat output

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xyzreader, PID: 13019
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xyzreader/crysalis.example.xyzreader.ui.ArticleListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.xyzreader-jVcseTSIIyMtEDk_Wlm8eg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.xyzreader-jVcseTSIIyMtEDk_Wlm8eg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at crysalis.example.xyzreader.ui.ArticleListActivity.onCreate(ArticleListActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Did you try to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` from `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`?

Comment: @cgb_pandey Yea. If you look at my imports, you'll see it there.

Comment: Yeah, its in the code but I was talking about xml.

Comment: Wooooooooooow, I'm a damned idiot haha. Yes, that worked. I updated the dependencies and imports accordingly but never attended to the xml files. Thank you @cgb_pandey

Comment: Haha, you should have looked into it earlier because exception clearly says the problem was while inflating the layout `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in your xml to

```
androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

And make sure to add below dependency in gradle module file

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
```

And in activity, make sure to add the right import

```
 import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've attached the build.gradle file. I tried using that dependency and the androidx.support.v4 dependency as well. No luck.

Comment: Hi @rclement5700 you can't use `androidx.support.v4` as it's not the right dependency; please use the above dependency instead; or you can share the module gradle  contents in the question.

Comment: if you look at my imports, you can see I didn't ultimately use the androidx.support.v4 dependency. I had used the import you've suggested. Thank you though. Do you have any more ideas? I'm still stuck.